# .includes doesn't return exact match. Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making a search engine in my expressJS backend and am having difficulty.  So far I have gotten the search function most of the time.  However, when getting an exact match, it won't work, on some words it doesn't even work at all.  I am having a hard time for finding the reason why.  Here is the offending code.

If I type Tom exactly I'll get Tom2222 but not Tom as an author.  Dudeman as a string can't be found at all as an author.

```
kbRoutes.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const query = req.query
  KB.find()
    .then(kbs => {
      if (query.title === undefined) {
        res.json(kbs)
      } else {
        var searchResults = []
        kbs.filter(kb => {
          if (kb) {
            console.log(typeof kb.author)
            console.log(typeof query.title)
            if (kb.body) {
              if (kb.body.toLowerCase()
                .includes(query.title.toLowerCase())) {
                searchResults.push(kb)
              }
            } else if (kb.title.toLowerCase()
              .includes(query.title.toLowerCase()) ||
              kb.title.toLowerCase() == query.title.toLowerCase()) {
              searchResults.push(kb)
            } else if (query.title.toLowerCase() == kb.author.toLowerCase()) {
              // || kb.author.toLowerCase().includes(query.title.toLowerCase())) {
              console.log(kb.author)
              searchResults.push(kb)
            } else if (kb.type) {
              if (kb.type.toLowerCase().includes(query.title.toLowerCase())) {
                searchResults.push(kb)
              }
            }
            return searchResults
          }
          return searchResults
        })
        res.json(searchResults)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: "some words" ... an example would help

Comment: added example  my apologies on that

Comment: It's likely the values are not what you think. Please provide the EXACT values that lead to the unexpected results. `'Tom'.toLowerCase().includes('Tom'.toLowerCase())` returns `true` as expected.

Comment: I'm typing everything in in lower case.  Sorry.  tom is what i'm typing in.  tom is also the name in the database.

Comment: I can see the values going in and out with my  console.log() under the filter.

Comment: Well, if you see them, please provide them and tell how my example is different than yours then.

Comment: You made me realize that the problem was not with the includes statement, and you have shown me the path.  Thank you sir.  I'm posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was a problem with my first if statement.  I have resolved.  Here is the non offending code

```
kbRoutes.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const query = req.query
    KB.find()
        .then(kbs => {
            if (query.title === undefined) {
                res.json(kbs)
            } else {
                var searchResults = []
                kbs.filter(kb => {
                    if (kb.body.toLowerCase()
                        .includes(query.title.toLowerCase())
                        || kb.title.toLowerCase()
                            .includes(query.title.toLowerCase())
                        ||
                        kb.author.toLowerCase()
                            .includes(query.title.toLowerCase())
                        ||
                        kb.type.toLowerCase().includes(query.title.toLowerCase())
                    ) { searchResults.push(kb) }
                    return searchResults
                })
                res.json(searchResults)
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
});
```